# Repeat texture on all surface without stretch jogl ES

Tags: android, jogl

i want repeat a texture automat without stretch , example , if have a texture 256x256 and one 512x512 , secound texture (512 x 512) is big like square and no repeat , but first need repet 4 time , but i want do automat , i know if i set param to texture like

```
{0,0 ,0,4,4,4,4,0}
```

first texture will repeat 4 time , but if change texture dimension need change again coord. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase very carefully for anyone to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't use the term "jogl ES". I already explained that the default Java binding for the OpenGL-ES API under Android is called "Android OpenGL". JOGL-ES was merged with JOGL several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glTexParameteri with GL_REPEAT, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S and GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T.

You have to pass some texture coordinates from 0.0 to 2.0 so that the texture is repeated 4 times (2 * 2).

Comment: yes but ideea is i want make that dinamic , that mean every time when change texture need change and coord